# Highcharts php data array

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I am struggling to get values added into the array at specific points.
What I am looking for is to create and empty array, take the resultset from the database and depending on whether they are global or local create the PHP array listed below. The problem is that no matter what I try I can't get the array to look like below.

Either values are being replaced, or arrays being replaced or values being added into wrong places

This is my empty array and I am trying to loop each resultset into the array and then how many sold in the day.

```
$test = array();

foreach($globalDatabase as $value)
{
    $test['global'][] = array('name'=>$value->type, 'data' => array($value->day,$value->quantity) );
}

foreach($localDatabase as $value)
{
    $test['local'][] = array('name'=>$value->type, 'data' => array($value->day,$value->quantity) );
}
```

This is what I need it to look like so that it ends up looking like this, which is the output format I need it to be in so it is compatible with highcharts

```
    $test = array(
        'global'=>array( 
                array(
                    'name'=>'CARS', 
                    'data' => array(
                        array('mon',1),
                        array('tue',1)
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'name'=>'BIKES', 
                    'data' => array(
                        array('mon',1),
                        array('tue',1)
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'name'=>'BOATS', 
                    'data' => array(
                        array('mon',1),
                        array('tue',1)
                    )
                ),
        ),
        'local'=>array(                    
                array(
                    'name'=>'CARS', 
                    'data' => array(
                        array('mon',1),
                        array('tue',1)
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'name'=>'BIKES', 
                    'data' => array(
                        array('mon',1),
                        array('tue',1)
                    )
                ),
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I take it that your data rows pulled from the table are 'flat', meaning each row has only a single value each for 'type', 'day', and 'quantity', with no nesting.
Going on that assumption, you may just need to group your data by common attributes similar to the following:

```
$databases = array('global'=>$globalDatabase, 'local'=>$localDatabase);
$workData = array('global'=>array(), 'local'=>array());
foreach($databases as $dbType=>$workDb)
{
    foreach ($workDb as $value) {
        if(!array_key_exists($value->type, $workData[$dbType])) {
            $workData[$dbType][$value->type] = array();
        }
        $workData[$dbType][$value->type][] = array($value->day, $value->quantity);
    }

}

$test = array();
foreach ($workData as $type=>$workRow) {
    foreach ($workRow as $dataKey=>$dataRow) {
        $test[$type][] = array('name'=>$dataKey, 'data' => $dataRow );
    }
}
```